# How to define/implement this interface with generics in a simpler way?

Tags: java

I'm working in a Genetic Algorithm and I want it as abstract as possible to be able to reuse the GA. I defined and implemented a Population Interface, and well it works, but I'm sure that's not the best way to do it. I don't have great experience with Java Generics. Is there an easier way of defining and implementing the Population interface (e.g. maybe avoid a cast conversion? avoid a new list in getChromosomes() ?)

```
public interface Population
{
    void addChromosomes(List<? extends Chromosome> chromosomes);

    List<Chromosome> getChromosomes();

    // More code here ...
}

public class TSPPopulation implements Population
{
    private List<TSPChromosome> chromosomes;

    @Override
    public void addChromosomes(List<? extends Chromosome> chromosomes) {
        for (Chromosome chromosome : chromosomes) {
            this.chromosomes.add((TSPChromosome) chromosome);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Chromosome> getChromosomes() {
        List<Chromosome> newList = new ArrayList<Chromosome>();
        for (TSPChromosome chromosome : chromosomes) {
            newList.add(chromosome);
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good old AI, I remember writing a code similar to this some few years ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a Bounded Wildcard in your interface:

```
public interface Population<T extends Chromosome>{
    void addChromosomes(List<T> chromosomes);

    List<T> getChromosomes();
}

public class TSPPopulation implements Population<TSPChromosome>
{
    private List<TSPChromosome> chromosomes;

    @Override
    public void addChromosomes(List<TSPChromosome> chromosomes) {
...
    }

    @Override
    public List<TSPChromosome> getChromosomes() {
...    
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not implement those features in the interface (eg make it into a class...)?

Comment: @dacwe: I did not understand? (You can not implement any thing in an interface - but i belive this is not what you meant.)

Comment: I meant that both `addChromosoms(..)` and `getChromosoms()` could be handled by an abstract base class.. (see my solution)

Comment: Of course, thats possible. But what way you choose: Abstract Class and Concrete Class, or Interface, Abstract Class and Concrete Class is very application specifig. - At least I prefer Interfaces (and maybe some abstract Class -- like List and AbstractList) over only an abstract class, because it is more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is extending a list (then use `addAll(...)` to add a list of Chromosoms to the list):

```
class Population<T extends Chromosome> extends ArrayList<T> {
}
```

But if you want the same structure I would make `Population` into a generic list class. That way both `add...` and `get...` methods can be handled in the generic base class. If you do want to override any other feature you just extend `Population` (`class TSPPopulation extends Population<TSPChromosome>`.

Usage:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Population<TSPChromosome> tspPopulation = new Population<TSPChromosome>();
    ... 
}
```

Implementation:

```
class Population<T extends Chromosome> {

    private List<T> chromosomes = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void addChromosomes(List<T> chromosomes) {
        this.chromosomes.addAll(chromosomes);
    }

    public List<T> getChromosomes() {
        return new ArrayList<T>(this.chromosomes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Extending the list sounds like a very simple but effective solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, probably the solution you were looking for! :)

Comment: I think I'm probably overcomplicating my GA. But this is working for me: A population interface like the one proposed by Ralph. A basic abstract implementation like in your solution, to end up with something like this: public abstract class BasicPopulation<T extends Chromosome> extends ArrayList<T> implements Population<T>

Comment: Then I would make `Popuplation` extend `List<? extends Chromosome>`. A population is still a list of chromosoms.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much safer if you made the Population generic itself:

```
public interface Population<T extends Chromosome> {

    void addChromosomes(List<T> chromosomes);

    List<T> getChromosomes();

}

public class TspPopulation implements Population<TspChromosome>{

    @Override
    public void addChromosomes(List<TspChromosome> chromosomes){
        // 
    }

    @Override
    public List<TspChromosome> getChromosomes(){
        //
    }

}
```

That way you would not need any casting in client code.

Answer (score 1):

I know GAs, and I would question whether your `Population` implementation actually needs to know which kind of `Chromosome` you put in. Do you really have different `Population` implementations depending on the `Chromosome` subclass? Or what you really want is to make sure you have the same subclass of `Chromosome` in a `Population`? In this last case, you can define the `Population` interface as others suggested, and the make a generic implementation (or skip the interface altogether):

```
public class PopulationImpl implements Population<T extends Chromosome> {
    private List<T> chromosomes;

    @Override
    public void addChromosomes(List<T> chromosomes) {
        this.chromosomes.addAll(chromosomes);
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getChromosomes() {
        return new ArrayList<T>(chromosomes);
    }
}
```

Be careful not to put too many generics, or you will end up with generics hell, or tons of casts which will make generics more annoying than useful.

Comment: You were totally right, I don't need the Chromosome interface, just a Chromosome class is enough. I tend to overcomplicate stuff sometimes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for instance:

```
public interface Population<T extends Chromosome>
{
    void addChromosomes(List<T> chromosomes);

    List<T> getChromosomes();

    // More code here ...
}

public class TSPPopulation implements Population<TSPChromosome>
{
    private List<TSPChromosome> chromosomes;

    @Override
    public void addChromosomes(List<TSPChromosome> chromosomes) {
        this.chromosomes.addAll(chromosomes);
    }

    @Override
    public List<TSPChromosome> getChromosomes() {
        return new ArrayList<TSPChromosome>(chromosomes);
    }
}
```